# How to enable developer mode on an iOS device without deploying an app to it using Xcode 6?

Tags: iphone, ipad, debugging, xcode6, ios8.1

I'm holding off on installing Xcode 6.1 due to horrible reviews it gets. Without that version, I cannot build on iOS 8.1 devices. Yet I have a couple devices running iOS 8.1 that I need to enable developer mode on. For iOS 8.0 devices I can just build and run any app on them and these devices would **get "developer" option in settings app.**

In Xcode 5.1 there was an explicit option to enable developer mode on devices or add them to portal, but  xCode 6.x does not seem to have that.

**How can I enable developer mode on an iOS 8.1 device using Xcode 6 ?**

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to do this any more?

I just installed an ad-hoc app with a development provisioning profile on a device with iOS 8.1 and I didn't need to enable development mode on the device.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 16 I saw this was disabled for some reason. But you can enabled it by Going into

```
Settings > Privacy and Security > Developer Mode > Enable
```

Xcode 14 shows this warning. But on Xcode 13 it is hidden and shows: ***Failed to Prepare device for Development***.

Comment: That option is hidden by default, it seems like you need to connect your device with Xcode first for the Developer Mode toggle to appear on Privacy and Security settings.